# Four displays for Alienware Aurora

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have an Alienware Aurora (late 2009) desktop and it has a graphics card that lets me hook up two displays to it. What do I need to do to add two more displays for a total of four? I haven't modified the computer at all on the inside other than adding an additional hard drive. I have Windows 8.1.

Some specs I found for my specific machine on the Dell website:

- DUAL IN-LINE MEMORY MODULE, 2G, 1333, 128X64, 8, 240, 2RX8 (quantity
  3)
- DUAL IN-LINE MEMORY MODULE, 1G, 1333, 128X64, 8, 240, 1RX8 (quantity
  3)
- PROCESSOR, I7-980X, 3.33, 12MB, GFT, B1
- CARD (CIRCUIT), GRAPHICS, GTX, 480, U121N

Would it be best to add an additional graphics card for two more displays? Or replace the current graphics card with a quad graphics card? Can my computer handle either? I game and watch videos on this machine. Most resource-intensive game I have played is Skyrim.

Edit: I don't expect to play Skyrim across all 4 monitors, just one is fine. However, sometimes I have multiple World of Warcraft clients open, one per display. The displays are 1920 x 1080.

Comment: If you intended to play skyrim across all 4 monitors the 480 is not enough to get playable frame rates.  If that is a desktop and not a laptop you should be able to upgrade, but you may have to upgrade your power supply as well.  What resolution are the displays? 1920 x 1080?

Comment: It is a desktop. I don't expect to play Skyrim across all 4 monitors, just one is fine. However, sometimes I have multiple World of Warcraft clients open, one per display. Not sure if that makes a difference. Yes, they are 1920 x 1080.